# Service worker's fetch listener is not getting triggered when fetch is used in web worker in case of Safari

Tags: google-chrome, safari, service-worker, web-worker

I am having a fetch listener attached to a service worker that listens for all the fetch calls made via the web browser. I am using this to serve from cache if it is already present. In case of chrome it is working fine even with the web worker. But in Safari fetch triggered from web worker is not invoking the listener attached.

Tried in macbook as well as ipad. I am expecting that the fetch in web worker should come to the service worker